# Как подключить базу данных mySQL с помощью С++

Tags: c++, sql, visual-c++

Я пытаюсь подключить базу данных с моего сайта и отображать некоторые строки с помощью С++. Поэтому я стараюсь сделать приложение, которое делает запрос выбора из таблицы из базы данных моего сайта. Теперь это должно быть возможно, потому что я видел множество приложений, которые делают это.

Как мне это сделать? Может ли кто-нибудь сделать пример и рассказать мне, какие библиотеки я должен использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Друже, не бойтесь пробовать искать нужное вам. [Вот этот код](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html) находится буквально за 10 секунд по запросу `mysql c++`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »
   AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```